# Форматирование строки + сравнение с другой строкой, чтобы вместо конкретных "слов" могло стоять что угодно

Tags: c#, строки, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота по поиску музыки Вк, хочу сделать метод, который бы при вводе команды **/getartistsong [artist] [count]** в телеграмме выводило список самых популярных песен (пока что). Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы на месте первой заглушки могло стоять любое слово, а на месте второй - любое число. Форматирование с помощью $ и @ результата не дало.

```
if (e.Message.Text == "/getartistsong @ @") {
    string[] myText = e.Message.Text.Split(' ');

    Artist = myText[1];
    Count = int.Parse(myText[2]);

    var audios = MyVkApi.GetMusicSearch(Artist, Count);

    foreach(var audio in audios) {
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId:e.Message.Chat,
            text:($ " > {audio.Artist} - {audio.Title}"),
        parseMode:
        ParseMode.Markdown);
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Text.StartWith("/getartistsong")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, это должно быть так:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^/getartistsong\\s+(?<artist>\\w+)\\s+(?<count>\\d+)");
Match match = regex.Match("/getartistsong hello 123");
if (match.Success) {
    string artist = match.Groups["artist"].Value;
    string count = match.Groups["count"].Value;
    // TODO: ...
}
```

Подробное описание регулярок советую читать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).